# Did not see any official documentation - are we allowed to leave showFeaturePoint in app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, arkit

I'm looking to allow users to view the debug option feature points to allow better node placement. I did not see any documentation stating against this use, but if so, is there an accepted way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think Apple’s app review team officially posts on SO, so you’re not likely to get authoritative answers here for any “will Apple approve/reject this” questions.

That said, they seems pretty fond these days of citing the [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) in rejections. 
(Read it [in comic book form](https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/App-Review-Guidelines-The-Comic-Book.pdf) if you prefer.) Between that and their list of [common rejections](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/), it’s not too hard to get a feel for what is and isn’t kosher.

In general, those guidelines suggest that for public APIs — those you see listed on developer.apple.com/documentation — you’re not going to get rejected just for using them. And if there’s a *how you use them* issue that’s cause for rejection, the guidelines are pretty explicit.

So as for [`rawFeaturePoints`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2887449-rawfeaturepoints), it seems very doubtful you’d get rejected for calling that API. What the docs for that API do warn about is relying on any specific behavior of the point cloud — e.g. trying to use the point cloud as the basis for an object detection algorithm of your own design is likely to waste your time.

And in fact, there seem to be several ARKit apps already on the store that use the feature points cloud as a simple user feedback mechanism... “wave the phone around until you see yellow dots” and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Rickster. Since no one seems to have a definite answer, ill try submitting and report back here with my success, or lack thereof.